# returning void* for a function/method return

Tags: c

Is it possible to have a function in C return a 'dynamic' return type

example

`printResult (NumOrChar());`

```
void* NumOrChar(void) {
   // return int  or char 
}

void printResult (void* input) {
  if (isdigit(input)) {
     printf("It's a number");
}
  else {
     printf("It's not a number");
}
```

Comment: You can return a `void*` but you still need to know somehow what type to cast it to afterwards

Comment: `cout << "foo";` you cannot bitshift by a string literal in **C**

Comment: Pointers are not integers. `return 7` and `input > 5` and `isdigit(input)` are all type errors.

Comment: @UnholySheep could you give me an example? I'm made edits in the question for more clarity.

Comment: in C strings consist of a series of characters that can contain digits or characters. isdigit checks an individual character to see if is 0..9, if not, it returns 0. you cant use isdigit on a void*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions can certainly return `void *`.  But that is a specific pointer type with properties that make it suitable for conveying pointers to objects of any type.  It is ***not*** a general-purpose wildcard type.  Moreover, it does not carry any kind of information about the actual type, if any, of the object to which it points, so there is no way to determine that type dynamically.  A C++ programmer might describe this situation as C not providing any RTTI.

Instead, you can return a type that can convey objects of a variety of types, known in advance, with a mechanism to discriminate among those.  For example,

```
union num_or_string {
    struct { _Bool is_num; };
    struct { _Bool _x1; int num; };
    struct { _Bool _x2; char *string; };
};

union num_or_string NumOrChar(void) {
    // return a union num_or_string containing an int or a char *
}

void printResult (union num_or_string) {
    if (num_or_string.is_num) {
        printf("It's a number: %d\n", num_or_string.num);
    } else {
        printf("It's a string: %s\n", num_or_string.string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Idiomatically known as a "[tagged union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union)"

Answer (score 2):

You can use _Generic in some circumstances

```
int func_int(int *p)
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return 5;  /* does not make too much sense */
}

float func_float(float *p)
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return 5.0f;  /* does not make too much sense */
}

double func_double(double *p)
{
    printf("%s\n", __FUNCTION__);
    return 5.0;  /* does not make too much sense */
}


#define func(p) _Generic((p), \
              int *: func_int, \
              float *: func_float, \
              double *: func_double)(p) \
```

Comment: Is this C for real?

Comment: @machine_1 what do you think it is.

Comment: Well, I've never seen this notation before. int *: func_int

Comment: [C11 Standard - 6.5.1.1 Generic selection](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.1.1)

Comment: it is time to learn almost 10 years old standard. A lots have changed from K&R :)

Comment: While it is part of the C11 standard, compilers did not implement it for several years. It was not supported in GCC until version 4.9 in 2014 (many Linux distros didn't move to 4.9 until a year or two later)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin it was a friendly joke with the smile, not educating :)

Comment: Oh yes, I got it, I was just really surprised how long it took for some distros to move to gcc 4.9. Or course distros like Arch were immediate, but distros like SuSE took until Leap. Lord knows what older distros like Stack or RedHat have. I know Debian Jessie made it to 4.9, but there it sits. So if @machine_1 has an older box, I wanted to make sure if he tried and it didn't work -- he had a little information to go on.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am a uC programmer. And I do not even remember the 4.9 :) 6.x sounds prehistoric for me. Actually often I install never versions than the "standard" disro versions, even if I do not update the libs.

Comment: For what it's worth, RHEL 7 uses GCC 4.8, always has, and always will.  I'm sure RHEL 8 uses something newer, but I'm not going to pay much attention to that until it comes out of beta.

Comment: @JohnBollinger you do not have to use the "system" one

Comment: No, of course not, but David was talking about when various distros moved to GCC 4.9 or later, so it's interesting to observe that RHEL is only doing so *right now*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a block of ifs, one can use a structure of function pointers as a virtual table, including `to_string`. The following dynamically creates the `Type`, which can be `Num` or `Letter`.

```
#include <stddef.h> /* offsetof */
#include <stdio.h>  /* [|s|sn]printf, fgets, stdin */
#include <stdlib.h> /* malloc, free, strtol */
#include <ctype.h>  /* isdigit */
#include <errno.h>
#include <assert.h>

struct Type;

typedef void (*TypeToString)(const struct Type *const, char (*const)[32]);
typedef void (*TypeAction)(struct Type *const);

struct Type {
    const struct TypeVt *vt;
};



/* Num extends Type. */

struct Num {
    struct Type base;
    int value;
};

static struct Num *num_upcast(struct Type *const type) {
    return (struct Num *)(void *)((char *)type - offsetof(struct Num, base));
}

static const struct Num *const_num_upcast(const struct Type *const type) {
    return (const struct Num *)(const void *)((const char *)type
        - offsetof(struct Num, base));
}

static void num_to_string(const struct Type *const type, char (*const a)[32]) {
    const struct Num *const num = const_num_upcast(type);
    snprintf(*a, sizeof *a, "%d", num->value); /* C99. */
}

static void num_delete(struct Type *const type) {
    struct Num *const num = num_upcast(type);
    free(num);
}



/* Letter extends Type. */

struct Letter {
    struct Type base;
    char letter;
};

static struct Letter *letter_upcast(struct Type *const type) {
    return (struct Letter *)(void *)((char *)type
        - offsetof(struct Letter, base));
}

static const struct Letter *const_letter_upcast(const struct Type *const type) {
    return (const struct Letter *)(const void *)((const char *)type
        - offsetof(struct Letter, base));
}

static void letter_to_string(const struct Type *const t, char (*const a)[32]) {
    const struct Letter *const letter = const_letter_upcast(t);
    sprintf(*a, "%c", letter->letter);
}

static void letter_delete(struct Type *const type) {
    struct Letter *const letter = letter_upcast(type);
    free(letter);
}



static const struct TypeVt {
    const char *name;
    const TypeToString to_string;
    const TypeAction delete;
} num_vt = { "num", &num_to_string, &num_delete },
    letter_vt = { "char", &letter_to_string, &letter_delete };

static void type_to_string(const struct Type *const t, char (*const a)[32]) {
    assert(t);
    t->vt->to_string(t, a);
}

static void type_delete(struct Type *const t) {
    assert(t);
    t->vt->delete(t);
}

static struct Type *num(const int value) {
    struct Num *num = malloc(sizeof *num);
    if(!num) return 0;
    num->base.vt = &num_vt;
    num->value = value;
    return &num->base;
}

static struct Type *letter(const char letter) {
    struct Letter *l = malloc(sizeof *l);
    if(!l) return 0;
    l->base.vt = &letter_vt;
    l->letter = letter;
    return &l->base;
}



static struct Type *read_type(void) {
    struct Type *type;
    char buffer[64];
    if(!fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin)) return 0;
    if(isdigit(buffer[0])) {
        long n;
        errno = 0;
        n = strtol(buffer, 0, 0);
        if(errno) return 0;
        type = num(n);
    } else {
        type = letter(buffer[0]);
    }
    return type;
}

int main(void) {
    char a[32];
    struct Type *type = 0;
    int is_success = 0;
    do {
        if(!(type = read_type())) break;
        type_to_string(type, &a);
        printf("\"%s\" is of type %s.\n", a, type->vt->name);
        is_success = 1;
    } while(0); {
        if(type) type_delete(type);
    }
    if(!is_success) return perror("Failure"), EXIT_FAILURE;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Probably overkill for your function, but as one has more types, this becomes increasingly attractive. One can consider a `union` of similar spaced types so that it could be allocated entirely on the stack.

```
$ bin/numorchar 
524645 3456542563456
"524645" is of type num.
$ bin/numorchar 
6245635724564357652654245634576
Failure: Result too large
$ bin/numorchar 
ata gfddsgsdg
"a" is of type char.
$ bin/numorchar 

"
" is of type char.
```

Answer (score -2):

I guess you are speaking about the **C#** feature (according to my [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic%20return%20type)).

In C, it's not possible unless doing it yourself (other answers show examples). It can be easy or hard depending of your needs. You should think about switching to another language if you really want this (they are sometimes called `variants` in them).